# Hadoop: How do datanodes register with the namenode?

Tags: hadoop

Do hadoop datanodes register themselves with the namenode by calling the namenode, or does the namenode have a list of datanodes and it reaches out to them.

I want to understand to better troubleshoot a problem with a new namenode I brought up (after a namenode failure) where it doesn't see any of the datanodes (but has the fsimage correct).

Comment: Data nodes heartbeat in to the name node. The name node does not reach out to data nodes. But that doesn't seem to be the question you really want to ask. ;)

Comment: No, that is the question, I wanted to keep it simple, it helps me know the architecture, what to expect so I can figure out why they're *not* heartbeating to the *new* namenode. Knowing the architecture is step 1. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: The new namenode - is this on the same address / port as the old name node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data nodes heartbeat in to the name node. The name node does not reach out to data nodes.

Even when retrieving data, the name node does not reach out to the data nodes. The name node will inform the client where the data is and the client will retrieve it from the data nodes. (To clarify, during an MR workflow the Job Tracker finds from the name node where the data is and assigns task trackers appropriately.)

Answer (score 3):

Each datanode keeps the namenode details in hdfs.conf file. And namenode keep names of all data nodes in slaves file. I think you should update your slaves files in namenode and master file in datanodes.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you have a working cluster (with `fs.default.name` in `core-site.xml` properly configured in datanodes) before hard shutting down the namenode.

When I shut down my namenode with `kill -9 pid`, my datanodes start to show in log:

> INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenodehost/192.168.0.35:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenodehost/192.168.0.35:8020. Already tried 1 time(s).
>
> ...
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenodehost/192.168.0.35:8020. Already tried 9 time(s).
>
> WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.net.ConnectException: Call to namenodehost/192.168.0.35:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at ...
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenodehost/192.168.0.35:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: namenodehost/192.168.0.35:8020. Already tried 1 time(s).
>
> ...

repeatedly until I load again my namenode. At that moment, datanodes' logs shows:

> INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeCommand action: DNA_REGISTER
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Finished generating blocks being written report for 1 volumes in 0 seconds
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting asynchronous block report scan
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Finished asynchronous block report scan in 10ms
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Reconciled asynchronous block scan with filesystem. 0 blocks concurrently deleted during scan, 0 blocks concurrently added during scan, 4 ongoing creations ignored
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Reconciled asynchronous block report against current state in 0 ms
>
> INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: BlockReport of 411 blocks took 0 msec to generate and 68 msecs for RPC and NN processing

Each datanode reconnects to the namenode and everything works ok.

Does this helps?

Comment: The last line forced me to think what you mean. Thanks :)

Comment: Can datanodes start before namenode? or there is always a startup dependency between namenode and datanodes?

Comment: @user1870400 You got me there, I don't know the answer with 100% confidence :P Usually namenode is started prior datanodes, and if you start HDFS service in a Cloudera CDH it always start the namenode  first.